# nan.h exception while installing AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am starting with AngularJS on a Windows 8.1 computer but have some problem to build the project.

Node verson : 5.1.1
NPM version : 3.5.1

When running

```
npm install
```

In the angular-phonecat folder it throws this error after a while :

> C:\Users\MyTest\angular-phonecat\node_modules\ws>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp (node
>   "C:\Users\MyTest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node
>   -gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild ) Building the projects in this solution one at a time.
>   To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.   bufferutil.cc
>   C:\Users\MyTest\angular-phonecat\node_modules\nan\nan.h(409): error
>   C2039: 'ExternalAsciiStringResource': is not a member of 'v8::String'
>   [C:\Users\MyTest\angular-phonecat\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\MyTest.node-gyp\5.1.1\include\node\v8.h(2078): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::String'

I have also installed Visual Studio 2015 and opened a C++ project that installed a couple of packages.

I have also specified to use VS2015 bulder for the npm.

If I run this

```
node -e "require('nan')"
```

I get node_modules\nan

What is wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same error for my project.  In [some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914721/failed-to-install-socket-io-by-npm), someone suggested below command. It worked for me.

```
npm install -g automattic/socket.io
```